# Удаление элемента из начала односвязного списка C++

Tags: c++, списки, односвязный-список

Написал программу для работы с односвязным списком. У каждого элемента есть название (name) и контент (content), который заполняется пользователем, а также ему присваевается системное время создания и счетчик обращений. Управление программой реализуется через консоль.

Проблема заключается в неправильной работе функции удаления (file *perish). Функция должна находить в списке элемент соответствующий введенному названию, при помощи функции find_name. Удаление из середины и конца списка работает правильно, но при удалении элемента в начале, его поле с названием (name) заполняется машинным кодом и остается в списке.

Прошу помочь мне решить эту проблему. Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class file
{
    public:
        char name[64];
        char content[256];
        int count;
        int day, month, year, min, hour;

        file *next;
};

file *add(file *head) //добавление узла в список
{
    file *pv = new file;
    pv->next = 0;

    cout << "Name of the file: ";
    cin.getline(pv->name, sizeof pv->name);

    pv->count = 0; 

    cout << "Input the content of the file: " << endl;;
    cin.getline(pv->content, sizeof pv->content);

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    pv->day = st.wDay;
    pv->month = st.wMonth;
    pv->year = st.wYear;
    pv->hour = st.wHour;
    pv->min = st.wMinute;

    if(head)
    {
        file *temp = head;
        while(temp->next) 
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = pv;
    }
    else
        head = pv;
    return head;

}

void print(file *head) //вывод списка на экран
{
    if(head == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "The catalog is empty!";
    } 
    else
    {
        while(head != 0){
            cout << head->name << "\t" << "\t" << head->day << "." << head->month << "." << head->year << " " << head->hour << ":" << head->min << "\t" << "\t" << head->count << endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}

file *find_name(file *pv, char *name, file** prev){ //нахождение файла в списке по имени
    *prev = 0;

    while(pv)
    {
        if(strstr(pv->name, name)) return pv;
        *prev = pv;
        pv = pv->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

file *perish(file *head) //удаление найденного по имени файла
{
    char name[64];
    system("cls");
    cout << "Input the name: ";
    cin.getline(name, sizeof name);

    file *prev;
    file *pv = find_name(head, name, &prev);
    if(pv)
    {
        if(pv == head) 
            head = head->next; 
        else 
            prev->next = pv->next;
        delete pv;
    }
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    file *head = 0;

    char ckey;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "1 - Add file to the catalog\n";
        cout << "2 - Open the catalog\n";
        cout << "3 - Delete the file\n";
        cout << "4 - Exit\n";

        ckey = _getch();
        system("cls");

        if(ckey == '1') head = add(head);

        else if(ckey == '2')
        {
            cout << "Name" << "\t" << "\t" << "Date" << "\t" << "\t" << "\t" << "Count" << endl;
            print(head);
        }
        else if(ckey == '3') perish(head);
        else if(ckey == '4') 
        {
            cout << "Closing..." << endl;   
        }
        else continue;
        _getch();

    } while(ckey != '4');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во первых лучше эти функции делать членом класса, во вторых такие вопросы легко решаются с  помощью отладчика .  Ну и наконец, если даже исправить ошибку, то код останется не очень хорошим.  На вашем месте я бы переписал все...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
else if(ckey == '3') perish(head);
```

Как я понял сдесь вы удаляете объекты. А теперь смотрим на функцию удаления:

```
file *perish(file *head)
```

Сдесь вы возвращаете значение. Что это за значение? А это у нас наш `head` - если произошло удаление первого элемента, то `head` меняется. Вот только изменение происходит не в функции - она возвращает новое значение, которое должно быть присвоено `head`. Тоесть должно быть так:

```
else if(ckey == '3') head = perish(head);
```

Ну а код действительно плох, так с классами не поступают.

Answer (score 0):

Начну с реализации:
лучше для ListNode реализовать либо свой мини класс, либо структуру в виде:

```
template <class V>
class ListNode {
private:
    V value;
    ListNode <V> *next;
public:
    template <class _V> friend class List;
protected:
};
```

А уже всё остальное уже реализовать в виде класса с указателем *first

Тогда метод класса на удаление элемента должен иметь примерно следующий вид:

```
template <class V>
void List::remove (ListNode * rm) {
    if (rm == first) {
        first = first->next;
    } else {
        ListNode <V> * c = first;
        while (c->next != rm) { c = c->next; }
        c->next = c->next->next;
    }
    delete rm; // Если память под элемент была выделена через new
    return;
}
```